# Error to use DBI::mySQL

Tags: mysql, perl, cpan, dbi

I started learning coding two weeks ago without having any IT background so far. I have been stuck the problem mentioned in the title. I wrote the code as

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use utf8;
use DBI;

my $dsn = 'DBI:mysql:database=DATABASENAME;host=HOSTNAME';
my $user = "USERNAME";
my $password = "PASSWORD";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$user, $password, or die "cannot connect to MySQL: $DBI::errstr");

my $id=1;
my $query = "test";
my $email = "test";
my $sql_insert = " INSERT INTO TABLENAME (id,query, email) values ($id, $query,$email) ";
my $insert = $dbh ->prepare ($sql_insert);
$insert ->execute;
$insert -> finish;
$dbh -> disconnect;
```

However, I got the error message from command line.

> Can't connect to data source 'PASSWORD' because I can't work out what
>   driver to use (it doesn't seem t o contain a 'dbi:driver:' prefix and
>   the DBI_DRIVER env var is not set) at DBItest.pl line 13.

I deleted some comments from the code so the sentence at the end mentioning line would be different.

Do you have any good idea to fix this problem? I'm trying to use mySQL on Freehostia.

Answer (score 3):

At a minimum, you have a typo here:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$user, $password, or die "cannot connect to MySQL: $DBI::errstr");
                                            ^ HERE
```

It should be

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$user, $password) or die "cannot connect to MySQL: $DBI::errstr";
```

Also, always use warnings. You would have gotten a warning like so, pointing you right at the problem:

```
Useless use of private variable in void context at yourFile.pl line 11
```

Comment: Yup, that will fix the OP's instant problem.  The `or` makes the preceding variables understood as a list evaluated in a scalar context, which means evaluated as the last element of the list, which is `$pass` ("PASSWORD") in this case.  Great point about `warnings`, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot AKHolland! Now I have different error massage concerning SQL syntax but can proceed my coding! I really appreciate your help!